# Intellij: save tomcat path in exported run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7, war

I'm trying to copy an IntelliJ Tomcat Run Config between 2 linux VMs, but the Application server path doesn't get saved.
Is there a way to save the path to the Application server in the Run Config xml?

I copied a Tomcat Server Run Configuration xml from one VM to another. The destination sees the Run Config and it keeps all the configs (vm args, deployment, tasks, ports) except for the "Application server".
I see that there is no hardcoded path to the Application server in the Run Config xml file.
Some paths to Tomcat are saved in .cache/JetBrains/.../tomcat/<BASE_DIRECTORY_NAME>/conf/[catalina.properties/server.xml]. Should I also move these files between VMs? I would rather not.

The VMs have the same directory structure.
Intellij version: 2022.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application server is the IDE-wide setting, and the actual paths to the servers are stored in `options/javaeeAppServers.xml` file under the [IDE configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory).

These are not meant to be shared between different operating systems.

Run configuration only references the app server by its name.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can share this file since the VMs have the same OS and directory structure.